# How would I prove $|a_n−a_1|+\sum_{i=1}^{n−1} |a_i−a_{i+1}|= \sum k_ia_i$?

Tags: calculus, summation, proof-writing, telescopic-series

How would I prove $|a_n−a_1|+\sum_{i=1}^{n−1} |a_i−a_{i+1}|= \sum k_ia_i$ for every $k_i \in \{-2, 0, 2\}$ and $\sum k_i = 0$?

I have a feeling we have to use telescoping method which then gets me $|a_n-a_1|+|a_1-a_n|$. Is this correct and where would I go from here?

Comment: The quantifiers are not clear.  I assume you mean that "there exists a selection $\{k_i\}_{i=1}^n$ such that the desired equality holds, each $k_i\in \{\pm 2, 0\}$ and $\sum k_i=0$", yes?

Comment: @lulu Sorry about that. You are right. So the question above is my claim and i have to prove this. I think what you have just said is correct and what i am looking for.

Comment: Extend indexing by periodicity, $$\sum_{i=1}^n |a_i - a_{i+1}| = \sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i (a_i - a_{i+1}) = \sum_{i=1}^n (\epsilon_{i}-\epsilon_{i-1})a_i$$
where $\epsilon_i = \begin{cases} +1, & a_i \ge a_{i+1}\\ -1, & a_i < a_{i+1}\end{cases}$. Now $\pm 1 - \pm 1 = 0, \pm 2$

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) throughout.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $a_i\ne a_{i+1}$ for all $i$ (cyclically). Then

- $k_i=-2 \quad\iff\quad a_{i-1}>a_i \ \  \wedge \ \ a_i<a_{i+1}$,
- $k_i=2\quad\iff\quad a_{i-1}<a_i \  \ \wedge \ \ a_i>a_{i+1}$,
- $k_i=0 \quad\iff\quad a_{i-1}>a_i>a_{i+1} \ \ \vee \ \ a_{i-1}<a_i<a_{i+1}$.

In words: $k_i=-2$ iff $a_i$ is a local minimum, $k_i=2$ iff $a_i$ is a local maximum, and $k_i=0$ otherwise. There have to be an equal nuber of local maxima and minima. Therefore $\sum_{cycl}k_i=0$.